# Android ListView not updating after calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a custom list adapter and get data to fill it via a Asynctask that gets data from a webserver.

This all seems to work fine however when I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` the listview does display the information below is my code:

```
public class my_Activity extends Activity {
    ...
    ListView accounts;
    static MyListAdapter m_adapter;
    private ArrayList<Account> accountslist;
    LoadAllAccounts l = new LoadAllAccounts();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    int userID;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray products = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  productsList;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.account);
        SharedPreferences perfs = getSharedPreferences(CFG.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        userID = perfs.getInt("USERID", 0);
        accounts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.accounts_list);
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        l.execute();
        accountslist = new ArrayList<Account>();
        m_adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row_layout,
                accountslist);
        accounts.setAdapter(m_adapter);

        accounts.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                Account Item = (Account) (accounts.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
                Intent i = new Intent(Account_Activity.this,
                        Balance_Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("Account", Item.getID());
                startActivityForResult(i, 1000);
            }
        });
            ...
    }

    class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Account> {

        private ArrayList<Account> items;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Account> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
            }
            Account o = items.get(position);
            if (o != null) {
                TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ptitle);
                TextView bb = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.balance);

                if (tt != null) {
                    tt.setText(Integer.toString(o.getID()));
                }
                if (bb != null) {
                    bb.setText("Balance: " + o.getBalance());
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }

    class LoadAllAccounts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Account_Activity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Accounts. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("USERID", Integer
                    .toString(userID)));
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(CFG.url_all_accounts,
                    "GET", params);

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(CFG.TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray("lists");
                    productsList.clear();

                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString("ACCOUNTID");
                        String name = c.getString("BALANCE");
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put("ACCOUNTID", id);
                        map.put("BALANCE", name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    for (int i = 0; i < productsList.size(); i++) {

                        Account list = new Account(
                                Integer.parseInt(productsList.get(i).get(
                                        "ACCOUNTID")),
                                Integer.parseInt(productsList.get(i).get(
                                        "BALANCE")));
                        accountslist.add(list);

                    }
                    m_adapter.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < accountslist.size(); i++) {
                        m_adapter.add(accountslist.get(i));
                    }
                    m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

My Account class:

```
public class Account {
    int accountID;
    int Balance;

    Account(int id, int b){
        accountID = id;
        Balance = b;
    }

    int getID(){
        return accountID;
    }

    int getBalance(){
        return Balance;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Account object with ID: "+accountID+" and balance: "+Balance;
    }
}
```

and the list row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ptitle"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ptitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".70" 
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="18dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="test"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/balance"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".70"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Remove all below codes in `OnCreate()`

```
    accountslist = new ArrayList<Account>();
    m_adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row_layout,
            accountslist);
    accounts.setAdapter(m_adapter);
```

Add that inside `onPostExecute` like below

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                accountslist = new ArrayList<Account>();
                for (int i = 0; i < productsList.size(); i++) {

                    Account list = new Account(
                            Integer.parseInt(productsList.get(i).get(
                                    "ACCOUNTID")),
                            Integer.parseInt(productsList.get(i).get(
                                    "BALANCE")));
                    accountslist.add(list);

                }
                m_adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row_layout, accountslist);
                accounts.setAdapter(m_adapter);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why do we initialise a new adapter for each service call, cant we reuse the adapter using listview.getadapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
My suggesstion will be try adding the values to the list and call
listview.getadapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
in the last line

Answer (score 0):

Not use `notifyDataSetChanged();` in `run()` but at the end.