# Android ListView not udpating after calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am not sure why, but the ListView is not updating/redrawing after calling notifyOnDataSetChanged(). I have also tried calling invalidateViews() on the list view, but that also has not worked. Any suggestions? Should I override notifyOnDataSetChanged()?

**Here is the ListActivity**

```
    package com.example.czhou.myapplication2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentProviderOperation;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Created by czhou on 1/18/2015.
 */
public class SudokuListActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    public static String[] fileNames;
    public SudokuListAdapter mAdapter;
    public static File[] files;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> selected = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         Context c = this;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

         ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        lv.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                                  long id, boolean checked) {
                if (checked) {
                    if (selected.indexOf(position) == -1) {
                        selected.add(position);
                    }
                }
                // Here you can do something when items are selected/de-selected,
                // such as update the title in the CAB
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.delete:
                            List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<String>();
                        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(fileNames));
                        for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
                            toRemove.add(fileNames[selected.get(i)]);
                        }


                            lst.removeAll(toRemove);
                        for (int j = 0; j < toRemove.size();j++) {
                            File file = getFileStreamPath("puzzle" + toRemove.get(j));
                            file.delete();
                        }
                            fileNames = lst.toArray(fileNames);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                        mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu for the CAB
                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_list_cab, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                // Here you can make any necessary updates to the activity when
                // the CAB is removed. By default, selected items are deselected/unchecked.
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // Here you can perform updates to the CAB due to
                // an invalidate() request
                return false;
            }
        });




        files = c.getFilesDir().listFiles();
        fileNames = new String[files.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fileNames[i] = files[i].getName().substring(6,files[i].getName().length());
        }


        mAdapter = new SudokuListAdapter(this,R.layout.row,fileNames);
        lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_list_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Context c = this;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add:
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yy hh:mm:ss a");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                String fn = "puzzle" + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
                SudokuGen sg = new SudokuGen();
                CellField cf = sg.generate();

                FileOutputStream outputStream;

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                        if (cf.field[i][j].isEditable) {
                            sb.append(",");
                        } else {
                            sb.append(".");
                        }
                        if (cf.field[i][j].isWrong) {
                            sb.append("!");
                        } else {
                            sb.append(".");
                        }

                        sb.append(cf.field[i][j].getValue());
                    }
                }

                try {

                    outputStream = openFileOutput(fn, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    outputStream.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
                    outputStream.close();
                    System.out.println("Saving... ");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SudokuGameActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("FILE",fn);
                startActivity(intent);
            break;
            default:

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        System.out.println("restarting.. ");
        Context c = this;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);




        files = c.getFilesDir().listFiles();
        fileNames = new String[files.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fileNames[i] = files[i].getName().substring(6,files[i].getName().length());
        }


        mAdapter = new SudokuListAdapter(this,R.layout.row ,fileNames);
        lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        lv.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                                  long id, boolean checked) {
                if (checked) {
                    if (selected.indexOf(position) == -1) {
                        selected.add(position);
                    }
                }
                // Here you can do something when items are selected/de-selected,
                // such as update the title in the CAB
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.delete:
                        List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<String>();
                        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(fileNames));
                        for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
                            toRemove.add(fileNames[selected.get(i)]);
                        }


                        lst.removeAll(toRemove);
                        for (int j = 0; j < toRemove.size();j++) {
                            File file = getFileStreamPath("puzzle" + toRemove.get(j));
                            file.delete();
                        }
                        fileNames = lst.toArray(fileNames);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                        mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu for the CAB
                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_list_cab, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                // Here you can make any necessary updates to the activity when
                // the CAB is removed. By default, selected items are deselected/unchecked.
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // Here you can perform updates to the CAB due to
                // an invalidate() request
                return false;
            }
        });

        super.onRestart();
    }


}
```

**Here is the ListAdapter**

```
package com.example.czhou.myapplication2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

/**
 * Created by czhou on 1/18/2015.
 */
public class SudokuListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    String data[];
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public  SudokuListAdapter(Context context,int id,String data[]){
        super(context,id,data);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return data[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.date);
        text.setText(data[position]);
        System.out.println("pos: " + position);

//        Bundle b = new Bundle();
//        b.putString("FILE","puzzle" + data[position]);
        SudokuPreviewView view = (SudokuPreviewView) vi.findViewById(R.id.preview);
        view.setData("puzzle" + data[position]);
        return vi;
    }


    public void setData(String[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void updateData(String newData[]) {
        this.data = newData;

    }
}
```

**Here is the row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <com.example.czhou.myapplication2.SudokuPreviewView
        android:layout_width="203dp"
        android:layout_height="258dp"
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        custom:mCell="15dp"
        custom:mTextSize="7sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Last played: 1/1/1"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ListView not updating after calling notifyDataSetChanged()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685696/android-listview-not-updating-after-calling-notifydatasetchanged)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are modifying the collection `fileNames` and not `data` inside your adapter which is why you're not seeing any updates to your `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
fileNames = lst.toArray(fileNames);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You assign fileNames but you never set this data in the Adapter. The Adapter is notified but it still has the old data.

The reference fileNames is pointing to something different than your Adapter's data.

This should work:

```
fileNames = lst.toArray(fileNames);
mAdapter.setData(fileNames);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Another thing I noticed is that you are doing I/O on the UI thread, consider using a separate thread for that. I only had a quick look at the code, didn't check if it actually works.

Edit:

ArrayAdapter has its own methods for adding/removing items, so you don't actually need to do this with your custom methods. Maybe this works for you:

```
fileNames = lst.toArray(fileNames);
mAdapter.clear();
mAdapter.addAll(fileNames); // this will update your list automatically
```

Alternatively, you can use your List directly:

```
mAdapter.clear();
mAdapter.addAll(lst);
```

Comment: Please try my edited solution, this is how I do it in my current project.